# Closed gravitational orbits and gradient systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I am currently studying non-linear dynamics on my own time. One of the theorems in the material is that systems that can be written as gradient problems cannot have closed orbits i.e. systems like
$$\dot{x}=-\nabla V.\tag{1}$$

Isn't this the general form of a gravitational system with $V$ being the gravitational potential (or other conservative systems) and $x$ being the momentum? What am I missing here, knowing that such problems (gravity and like) often have closed orbits?

See this for reference http://www.cds.caltech.edu/archive/help/uploads/wiki/files/224/cds140b-perorb.pdf

Comment: Isn't it usually the _force_, rather than the momentum, that's proportional to the gradient of potential? If so, then the gravitational system should be of the form $\ddot{x}=-\nabla V$, not $\dot{x}=-\nabla V$.

Comment: I am taking x=mv to be the momentum. x is not the position. So rate of change of momentum $(\dot{x})$ is the force which is given by the gradient of the potential. Did I miss something?

Comment: In order to be consistent with the definition of gradient system (see e.g. http://www.cds.caltech.edu/archive/help/uploads/wiki/files/224/cds140b-perorb.pdf), your system must be of the form $\dot{x}=-\nabla V(x)$, so your potential is momentum-dependent if $x$ is momentum. This is clearly not equivalent to a gravitational system, where $V$ is dependent on position. This is why omitting the arguments of functions is sometimes dangerous.

Comment: I knew I was missing something, but couldn't figure our what. Great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. OP's eq. (1) is [Aristotelian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotelian_physics) $$ m\dot{q}^i~=~-\frac{\partial V(q)}{\partial q^i} 
   \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad 
   V_i-V_f ~=~2 \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \! \mathrm{d}t ~E_{{\rm kin}}  \tag{A}$$ 
   This is dissipative. There are no$^1$ closed orbits.
2. In contrast [Newtonian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)
   $$ m\ddot{q}^i~=~-\frac{\partial V(q)}{\partial q^i}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad 
   V_i+E_{{\rm kin},i} ~=~ V_f+E_{{\rm kin},f}  \tag{N}$$
   preserves [mechanical energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_energy) for conservative forces.

--

$^1$ *Indirect one-line proof:* A closed orbit would mean that the LHS of the second equality in eq. (A) is zero, but the RHS is clearly positive. Contradiction. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

What's confusing you is the fact that you have implicitly omitted the argument of $V$. The definition of gradient system (http://www.cds.caltech.edu/archive/help/uploads/wiki/files/224/cds140b-perorb.pdf) is such that

$$\dot{x}=-\nabla V(x)$$

so if you define $x$ to be momentum, then you now have a potential which is dependent on momentum, which is not equivalent to a gravitational system (it has a potential that depends only on position).